# What is the purpose of the 'ssh' group?

Tags: linux, ssh, users, group, openssh

There is a system user named `sshd` on my system, and a group named `ssh`:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep ssh
sshd:x:120:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
$ cat /etc/group | grep ssh
ssh:x:117:
```

My guess is the user `sshd` allows OpenSSH to use port `22`, and access `/etc/ssh` without having to run as root.

I'm assuming the `ssh` group was also created by OpenSSH, but I can't find any mention of it [*in the documentation*](http://www.openssh.com/manual.html).

What is the purpose of this new user?

Comment: Note that the `sshd` user's `/etc/passwd` entry specifies a login shell `/usr/sbin/nologin`, so `sshd` cannot login, and has to be accessed via setuid stuff. `man -a passwd`.

Answer (score 9):

Only the root user is capable of creating sockets in privileged ports eg port < 1024.

The `ssh` user/group is used with privilege separation in openSSH.

The daemon is running a process with user `root`, and when receiving connections, running in a `chroot` environment with the non-privileged user `sshd`.

Or put other way, it runs the part of the operations that needs privileges as `root`, and the part they can isolate as a non-privileged user.

I will leave a link here of the project, which also has a link to a paper about the subject.

http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/ssh/privsep.html

The paper:

http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/papers/privsep.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The `ssh` user is created by openssh-client.
It is set as the group of the ssh-agent binary, which has setgid set.
Recently the group was renamed to `_ssh`, to signify that it is for internal use only.

Source: [openssh-client postinst script](https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/-/blob/eac38305fc5d8eb8301a106294cf6c79447bdeb3/debian/openssh-client.postinst)

Comment: Are you sure that this `_ssh` group name is not distro dependent?